# R does not import values as numbers

Tags: r, type-conversion

Basic data was generated using a SQL query and the intention is to process data in R. However, while importing from a `.csv` or from `.xlsx`, R imports numbers as characters in spite of changing the data-type in the built-in `import` tool. Further, while performing basic arithmetic operations, following errors were encountered:
 `In Ops.factor((data$A), (data$B)) :‘/’ not meaningful for factors`

Is there a simple way to solve this?

- Data-set was analysed using the `str()` function, which revealed that R imported the particular columns as `factors`.
- Used package `varhandle` and function `unfactor` to unfactorize the data
- Used `as.numeric` for some columns which were read as `characters` instead of `factors`
- Tried changing data-types in Excel before importing

  `data$A <- unfactor(data$A)`

  `data$B <- unfactor(data$B)`

  `data$PERCENTAGE <- (data$B)/(data$A)*100`

By what means can R import the data as per specified data-types?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data (`dput(data)`)?

Comment: Probably you are using `read.csv` without specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: It will help to provide [some example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Almost certainly, a column that you thought was numeric contains characters, which has caused conversion to factors because `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` was not specified.

Comment: I tried with `stringsAsFactors = F` , but got the following error `non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Again, will help to see the command used to read in the data.

Comment: Data1 <- read.csv("Z:/Data1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE). Will `fread` from `data.table` make a difference?

Comment: Provide example data. Maybe set `sep=","` for `read.csv`?

Comment: Example data is a bit difficult to provide....I understand it will help, but some confidentiality clauses are restrictive

Comment: Does the file have a header? If so and you don't include `header = TRUE`, that will introduce characters into the columns on the first row.

Comment: `data2 <- read.csv("Z:/Data1.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",as.is = !stringsAsFactors, 
         colClasses = NA,            
         na.string = "NA",          
         skip = 0,                  
         strip.white = TRUE,       
         fill = TRUE,              
         comment.char = "#",        
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE   )`      I used this code just now, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

For csv files I would recommend [read_csv](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) from Hadley Wickham's excellent [Tidyverse package](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/). It has intelligent defaults that cope with most things I throw at it.

For .xlsx, there is [read_excel](https://readxl.tidyverse.org), also from the Tidyverse package (there are other packages available).
Or, alternatively just  export a .csv from within Excel and use read_csv.

[Note the Tidyverse's will import these files as a "[tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org)" which is essentially a data frame on steroids without some of the headaches but is easily converted to a data.frame if you prefer.]